# Pthread in windows C gives error unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm trying to make pthread work,I'm using Visual Studio 2017.I downloaded pthread from NuGet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    Sleep(1);
    printf("Printing GeeksQuiz from Thread \n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    printf("Before Thread\n");
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code from Geek for Geeks.But compiling this give first of all timespec error which I fixed with a define but then I get this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_create referenced in function _main   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_join referenced in function _main
```

Tried to debug it in both x64 and x86 and gives the same error.Can anyone help?

Comment: When we compile a c program with "pthread.h" using gcc compiler, we use -pthread flag. Check if you are using it. 
This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975700/how-to-add-pthread-library-to-c-project-in-visual-studio-community-edition

Comment: Note: Nothing wrong with this "toy" program, but in any real program, if you `join()` a thread immediately after creating it, then you are kind of missing the entire point of using threads.

Comment: Have you added the pthread *library* to the *linker* command?

Comment: I'm using visual studio,is it the same with gcc compiler?And how do I add the library to the linker command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add pthread library to C++ project in Visual Studio Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975700/how-to-add-pthread-library-to-c-project-in-visual-studio-community-edition)

Comment: In this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975700/how-to-add-pthread-library-to-c-project-in-visual-studio-community-edition it requires me to download 3 headers from that website,I downloaded the pthread library using NuGet.I tried the solution provided by them,adding the pthreadVC2.lib as a dependency,and it gives Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'pthreadVC2.lib'